# Next.js 13 App directory error handling client exceptions

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, next.js, error-handling

Following the documentation on how to handle errors, [Routing: Error Handling](https://nextjs.org/docs/app/building-your-application/routing/error-handling), I have added `error.tsx` and `global-error.tsx` components to both nested routes and the root `app` directory.

Whenever I try to throw an error from client components (one that has `'use client'`), the error boundary is not triggered, and I'm left with an uncaught exception.

My question is, is there a way to handle client exceptions globally as well?

Comment: I'm also having the same problem, did you solve this problem?

Comment: There are issues created in here https://github.com/vercel/next.js/issues/50987 there seems a issues hence bug is created. this might be the general issue